# Como iterar un hash en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo este este hash

{"fecha"=>["5/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "8/2/2020", "5/1/2020"],"razon_social"=>["BAR", "MERCA", "FARMACIA", "QUIOSCO"], "cif"=>["2378863", "73465237", "83743733", "3453723"]}

y me gustaria iterarlo en una tabla de forma que el valor rellene el td, por ejemplo

```
    <tbody>
     <% @test.each do |key, value| %>
            <tr id="1">
                <td><%= value[fecha] %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td><%= value[razon_social] %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3">
                <td><%= value[cif] %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué quieres lograr?, ¿cómo se vería el resultado final (i.e. la tabla ya dibujada en _HTML_?

Comment: Quiero crear una tabla dinámica, desde el controlador tengo un WebService que recibe un fichero Json que transformo en un Hash y lo envio a la vista, en cada columa quiero que se copie el valor correspondiente tal y como e puesto en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías obtener el tamaño de los arreglos a partir del primer elemento del *hash* para iterarlo y mostrar los datos con la estructura que buscas; e.g.:

```
<tbody>
  <% @test.values.first.size.times do |i| %>
    <tr id="<%= i + 1 %>">
      <% @test.values.each do |value| %>
        <td><%= value[i] %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero por la respuesta, yo mas bien me refería a algo así 
 <tr id="1">
    <td>5/1/2020</td>
    <td>BAR</td>
    <td>2378863</td>
  </tr>

Comment: @IvanJC He actualizado la respuesta para mostrar la tabla de acuerdo a tu comentario; espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Gerry! perfecto ;)

Comment: @IvanJC De nada! Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic en la paloma). Suerte!